# How do I run a script on every memorial day of every year to come (The last Monday of May every year for ever)

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

My first attempt was to make a crontab like this:

```
 1 0 25,26,27,28,29,30,31 5 1 /path/to/file
```

But #linux on freenode said it wouldn't work.

I was thinking of setting one for the years to come, but crontab doesn't have a year field.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

--Edit

I think I found my solution with run-if-today script located

```
 http://xr09.github.io/cron-scheduling-for-the-fancy.html
```

I'll let you guys know.

--Edit

Yup, looks like this is what I have been looking for. I'm still taking suggestions.

Comment: what about `1 0 12 ? 5 MONL *`

Comment: sorry it's a quartz cron expression

Answer (score 0):

based on this other answer https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month.

Add a check before to execute command

```
0   12  25-31 5   *   [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

Note: the percent sign % must be escaped in cron command